# Syn flood attack reported by Apache fill up my physical memory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

This morning i've found a server (Ubuntu lts 12.04 on AWS EC2) under a syn flood attack, its physical memory was totally filled, so i've started checking why, but logs were quite normal, and a find from the root didn't shown an abnormal use of space, at that time i was totally lost until i've thought to restart Apache and guess what, the physical memory was back on track.

So there's someone who can give me a clue about this?

Thank you

Comment: Look at [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442).

Comment: i don't think this is what i've asked for

Comment: A SYN flood holds the Apache processes up and causes it to spawn additional children to handle the so-called "load" it's expecting. Since the flood simply holds the connections open, it spawns more and more eventually exhausting your memory. That's what's happening and what I linked will stop it.

Comment: I was missing the multi-process nature of my Apache instance, thank you!

Comment: You should try to block this through the firewall and not the web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attack was causing multiple children to spawn to handle the requests (which were bogus). This caused resource exhaustion as I noted in the comments.